# Getting error while trying to run sysinfo after setting derby_home and path

Tags: java, database, derby

I have download `db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin.zip` and unzip it in
`C:\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin` folder
then I set the `DERBY_HOME=db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin`
and `path = db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin\bin`
Permanently from control panel

but when I am trying to run this command

`E:\Java Codes\Embedded DB\derby tutorial>copy %DERBY_HOME%\demo\programs\toursdb\*.sql`

I am getting error:

```
C:\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin\index.html
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin\KEYS
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin\LICENSE
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin\NOTICE
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin\RELEASE-NOTES.html
The system cannot find the path specified.
        0 file(s) copied.
```

I am not able to run any command like sysinfo,ij etc

Comment: Try running `echo "%DERBY_HOME%"` to see the value, and to ensure there are no spaces in the value. I bet there is a trailing space, so the command became `copy C:\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin \demo\programs\toursdb\*.sql`, i.e. copying the content of the `C:\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin` folder to folder `\demo\programs\toursdb`, which doesn't exist, hence the error.

Comment: I think you made mistake in path setting. have you removed other paths values which is set by default? And the path you set need to be absolute not relative. i.e it shld start from C:\ and so on so forth